# Get full path to current node

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

If I have an `XPathNavigator` positioned on a node, how can I get an XPath expression that represents the path to that node, from the root?

For example, if the XML is:

```
<data>
    <class name='dogs'>
        <item name='doberman />
        <item name='husky' />
    </class>
    <class name='cats'>
        <item name='persian' />
        <item name='tabby' />
    </class> </data>
</data>
```

...then the path to the persian cat could be expressed as `/data/class[2]/item[1]`

I can enumerate the ancestors of the node in question with `SelectAncestors()` (or I could iteratively climb up the parent relationship with `SelectParent()`), but that doesn't get me the positional information.

Would I have to evaluate an XPath using `position()` for each ancestor, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  XPathNavigator objects are generally positioned on the root.  Once they are created, their positions cannot change.  Perhaps there is a way around this problem?

Comment: @Zenexer: if I use CreateNavigator().Select(expr) then that returns an XPathNodeIterator... but the XPathNodeIterator gives me an XPathNavigator for each selected node - positioned on said node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you're interested only in the xpath of xml elements, I implemented a brute force algorithm (i.e. traversing the XML structure) as extension methods on `XmlElement`. This is very similar to @Zenexer's answer, although I had already started on my own version when he posted his.

Also, intrigued by Alexei's tip about performance, I created a sort of test case using a somewhat complex XML file lyring around here. Then I implemented two versions of the same algorithm; one that depends on PreviousSibling, and other that iterates nodes sequentially. A third version relied on XPath's `position()` function, but it didn't work as expected and was discarded.

While you should check for yourself, in my machine the results showed **a significant performance advantage for the iterative version** -- 1.7s against 21s scored by the siblings version.

Importart: these extension methods are declared inside a `static class XmlElementExtension`.

### PreviousSibling version

```
    public static string GetXPath_UsingPreviousSiblings(this XmlElement element)
    {
        string path = "/" + element.Name;

        XmlElement parentElement = element.ParentNode as XmlElement;
        if (parentElement != null)
        {
            // Gets the position within the parent element, based on previous siblings of the same name.
            // However, this position is irrelevant if the element is unique under its parent:
            XPathNavigator navigator = parentElement.CreateNavigator();
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(navigator.Evaluate("count(" + element.Name + ")"));
            if (count > 1) // There's more than 1 element with the same name
            {
                int position = 1;
                XmlElement previousSibling = element.PreviousSibling as XmlElement;
                while (previousSibling != null)
                {
                    if (previousSibling.Name == element.Name)
                        position++;

                    previousSibling = previousSibling.PreviousSibling as XmlElement;
                }

                path = path + "[" + position + "]";
            }

            // Climbing up to the parent elements:
            path = parentElement.GetXPath_UsingPreviousSiblings() + path;
        }

        return path;
    }
```

### Iterative version

```
    public static string GetXPath_SequentialIteration(this XmlElement element)
    {
        string path = "/" + element.Name;

        XmlElement parentElement = element.ParentNode as XmlElement;
        if (parentElement != null)
        {
            // Gets the position within the parent element.
            // However, this position is irrelevant if the element is unique under its parent:
            XmlNodeList siblings = parentElement.SelectNodes(element.Name);
            if (siblings != null && siblings.Count > 1) // There's more than 1 element with the same name
            {
                int position = 1;
                foreach (XmlElement sibling in siblings)
                {
                    if (sibling == element)
                        break;

                    position++;
                }

                path = path + "[" + position + "]";
            }

            // Climbing up to the parent elements:
            path = parentElement.GetXPath_SequentialIteration() + path;
        }

        return path;
    }
```

### The test case

```
    private static void Measure(string functionName, int iterations, Action implementation)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            implementation();
        }

        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}ms", functionName, watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"location of some large and complex XML file");

        string referenceXPath = "/vps/vendorProductSets/vendorProductSet/product[100]/prodName/locName";

        Measure("UsingPreviousSiblings", 10000,
                () =>
                    {
                        XmlElement target = doc.SelectSingleNode(referenceXPath) as XmlElement;
                        Debug.Assert(referenceXPath == target.GetXPath_UsingPreviousSiblings());
                    });

        Measure("SequentialIteration", 10000,
                () =>
                {
                    XmlElement target = doc.SelectSingleNode(referenceXPath) as XmlElement;
                    Debug.Assert(referenceXPath == target.GetXPath_SequentialIteration());
                });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. People have spent so much time on this I'm almost sorry I asked the question! :-)   Note however that you have a copy-paste error in your "position" and "iteration" versions. At the point of the recursive call, both actually call your "siblings" version. That might explain why you saw no difference in performance? :-)

Comment: Gosh! My bad. Will update soon. Well, I actually spent more time than I would allow myself but it was quite fun and instructive! Good question nonetheless.

Comment: Corrected & edited. I also dropped the xpath position() version as it was incorrect.

Comment: Probably does not work for namespaced elements

Answer (score 2):

Untested; only works with XPathNavigator objects created from XmlDocument objects:

```
private static string GetPath(this XPathNavigator navigator)
{
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    for (XmlNode node = navigator.UnderlyingObject as XmlNode; node != null; node = node.ParentNode)
    {
        string append = "/" + path;

        if (node.ParentNode != null && node.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count > 1)
        {
            append += "[";

            int index = 1;
            while (node.PreviousSibling != null)
            {
                index++;
            }

            append += "]";
        }

        path.Insert(0, append);
    }

    return path.ToString();
}
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
XPathNavigator navigator = /* ... */;
string path = navigator.GetPath();
```

### However...

XPathNavigator objects are generally positioned on the root node. Once they are created, their positions cannot be changed, though you can use them to select descendants. Perhaps there is a way to avoid this problem altogether?  For example, if you just want the current node, you can use `XPathNavigator.UnderlyingObject`, as in the sample.

Comment: +1. Positional XPath is the way to go. Note that depending on implementation of nodes "PreviousSibling" may be extremely slow (if need to walk all children up to current one). Consider walking forward to current node. Note 2: be careful with attributes as they don't have position -0 just name.

Comment: @Zenexer: thanks, but alas I'm dealing with an XPathDocument. Had I realised that makes a difference, I would have mentioned that. Sorry.

Comment: @Zenexer: under what circumstances would node.ParentNode.ChildNodes.Count be zero? That seems like a contradiction...

Comment: @GaryMcGill It wouldn't.  But it might be 1.  That's what the test is.

Comment: Hmmm...`navigator.UnderlyingObject as XmlNode` returning `null` for me

Comment: @MickyD This only works with XmlDocuments, not XPathDocuments.  Are you using the latter?

Comment: Ohh!! Yes that's right.  I had to move over to using `XmlDocument` since yesterday because I needed to `DeleteCurrent` so now it's a _win win_.  Thanks :)  +1

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution with ParentNode. Simply go up until you reach the root node and remember every node name you pass along. Tested!

```
    // Get the node full path
    static string getPath(XmlNode node)
    {
        string path = node.Name;
        XmlNode search = null;
        // Get up until ROOT
        while ((search = node.ParentNode).NodeType != XmlNodeType.Document)
        {
            path = search.Name + "/" + path; // Add to path
            node = search;
        }
        return "//"+path;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you read the question fully. I would need to know the position at each step, e.g. /foo[3]/bar[2]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for XPathNavigator that is created from XPathDocument. It iterates up to the root while checking for every node in path it has sibling above or not.

```
    //returns full xpath, can make it extension method
    protected string GetFullXpath(XPathNavigator navigator)
    {
        var firstNodeEscape = navigator.NodeType == XPathNodeType.Attribute
                                ? "/@"
                                : "/";
        string path = string.Concat(firstNodeEscape, $"{navigator.Name}{GetXmlArrayIndex(navigator)}");
        while (navigator.MoveToParent())
        {
            path = string.Concat($"/{navigator.Name}{GetXmlArrayIndex(navigator)}", path);
        }

        return path;
    }

    //returns index of element in array, used inside GetFullXpath method to add node position in array to path
    private string GetXmlArrayIndex(XPathNavigator navigator)
    {
        var backwardsNavigator = navigator.Clone();
        var elementsBeforeCount = 0;
        while (backwardsNavigator.MoveToPrevious()) //true while has siblings
        {
            if (backwardsNavigator.NodeType != XPathNodeType.Element) continue;
            if (backwardsNavigator.Name == navigator.Name) elementsBeforeCount++;
            else break;
        }

        return elementsBeforeCount > 0
                    ? $"[{++elementsBeforeCount}]" //++ because xpath array indexes are 1-based
                    : string.Empty;
    }
```