# How can I know the index of a XML Tag

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get the index of my current XML tag ?

Example:

```
<User>
  <Contact>
    <Name>Lucas</Name>
  </Contact>
  <Contact>
    <Name>Andre</Name>
  </Contact>
    ...
</User>
```

I'm trying the code below

```
    foreach (var element2 in doc2.Root.Descendants())
    {
        String name = element.Name.LocalName;
        String value = element.Value;
    }
```

I want to know if I'm reading the first `<Contact>` tag, or the second, or the third...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the appropriate overload of [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869) will yield the index as you enumerate the collection.

```
var userContacts = doc2.Root
                       .Descendants()
                       .Where(element => element.Name == "Contact")
                       .Select((c, i) => new {Contact = c, Index = i});

foreach(var indexedContact in userContacts)
{
     // indexedContact.Contact
     // indexedContact.Index                 
}
```

*Note:  I added the .Where because .Descendants will recurse.*

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `for` statement, then you'll always know the index. I am making an assumption that `Descendants()` can be used in a for statement.

The other possibility it to create a count variable outside the `foreach`.

```
int count = 0
foreach (var element2 in doc2.Root.Descendants())
{
    String name = element.Name.LocalName;
    String value = element.Value;

    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `foreach` loop with a normal `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc2.Root.Descendants().Count(); i++)
{
    String name = doc2.Root.Descendants()[i].Name.LocalName;
    String value = doc2.Root.Descendants()[i].Value;
}
```

Then use `i` to see if you're reading the first, second, third, etc. tag.

There is no way to get the index of a foreach enumerator without using an external counter.. AFAIK.

This also presents an efficiency problem, as you have to process the Descendants method twice every loop iteration, so I recommend keeping a List representing the Descendants outside of the for loop, and then use it like this:

```
var desecendants = doc2.Root.Descendants().ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < descendants.Count; i++)
{
    String name = descendants[i].Name.LocalName;
    String value = descendants[i].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable as counter and put the result into an array. The problem here is, that you need to know the size of the array in advance.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var element in doc2.Root.Descendants()) {
     name[i] = element.Name.LocalName;
     value[i] = element.Value;
     i++;
}
```

with the use of a `List<T>` you don't have this problem

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
foreach (var element in doc2.Root.Descendants()) {
     list.Append(new KeyValuePair(element.Name.LocalName, element.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can with foreach, try using a normal for loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

To get the position of your current node without counters (as previous solutions pointed out) you'll need to write a function to build up a the XPath of your current XmlElement. The only way to do it is to traverse the document from your node using parent node and previous siblings. That way you'll be able to build up the exact XPath to access your node from the document. Here's a sample taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9221904/311115)

```
   public static string GetXPath_UsingPreviousSiblings(this XmlElement element)
    {
        string path = "/" + element.Name;

        XmlElement parentElement = element.ParentNode as XmlElement;
        if (parentElement != null)
        {
            // Gets the position within the parent element, based on previous siblings of the same name.
            // However, this position is irrelevant if the element is unique under its parent:
            XPathNavigator navigator = parentElement.CreateNavigator();
            int count = Convert.ToInt32(navigator.Evaluate("count(" + element.Name + ")"));
            if (count > 1) // There's more than 1 element with the same name
            {
                int position = 1;
                XmlElement previousSibling = element.PreviousSibling as XmlElement;
                while (previousSibling != null)
                {
                    if (previousSibling.Name == element.Name)
                        position++;

                    previousSibling = previousSibling.PreviousSibling as XmlElement;
                }

                path = path + "[" + position + "]";
            }

            // Climbing up to the parent elements:
            path = parentElement.GetXPath_UsingPreviousSiblings() + path;
        }

        return path;
    }
```

Assuming that's really what you really need, depending on the document size it could be resource intensive. If you only require the index, I'd recommend using one of the other methods.